# Simba ODBC Driver to EC2 Instance w/ MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, odbc, tableau-api

I have a Windows VM on my desktop that has Tableau-Desktop loaded. I have a mongoDB instance on my EC2 instance and want to be able to connect my desktop Tableau with my EC2 instance.

I'm using the Simba ODBC connector. I started to install the linux drivers onto my EC2 RHEL server but Simba support said that I should look into AWS Simba drivers and contact AWS support.

If I use ODBC option from Tableau I don't know how I would specify the .mem SSL key file to get access to my EC2 instance. Can anyone point me in the right direction? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need to install client drivers on your Linux instance? You should be able to remotely connect to mongo provided that you set up firewall access to allow it.

Comment: Yes, I can connect to Mongo on EC2 instance no problem. I am trying to setup Simba ODBC connector so that I can establish connection between Tableau and my mongo instance on EC2.

Comment: You should install the drivers on the VM running Tableau. Then within the ODBC connection setup, use the Simba to connect to your Mongo instance.

Comment: datasage is right, install the driver where you have Tableau and configure a DSN for the driver. The DSN configuration will allow you to configure the SSL settings and pick up the key file.

Comment: Thanks. I configured the DSN and added the SSL certificate file. I keep getting this error now.....                                                                  ([Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed)

Comment: I entered in my Host:[EC2 public IP], Port:27017, db: [my db name]. Not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: Ended up that the ODBC connector wasn't handling the SSL file nicely. I ended up having to turn SSL off on my AWS EC2 instance, which probably isn't good but ok for my testing purposes. After that than I was able to get it to work.